# How can I combine the results of two different MATCH clauses and return the combined result?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a node (:Person) that can have the following relations.

1. [:LIKE] an (:Artist) who [:PERFORMS] at an (:Event)
2. [:LIKE] a (:Host) who is [:HOSTING] an (:Event)
3. [:ATTENDS] an (:Event)

I'm trying to write a cypher query that returns all the Events that either

1. is being attended by the user 
   `(me:Person)-[:ATTEND]->(gig:Event)`
2. has an artist that the user likes performing 
   `(me:Person)-[:LIKE]->(a:Artist)-[:PERFORMS]->(gig:Event)`
3. is being hosted by a host that the user likes
   `(me:Person)-[:LIKE]->(h:Host)-[:HOSTING]->(gig:Event)`

I tried using a query like `match (me {emailId: 'abc@xyz.com'})-[attend:ATTEND]->(gig), (me)-[:LIKE]->(n)-[:PERFORM|HOSTING]-(gig2) return gig,gig2` but this only returns the desired results if the first part of the match clause, which matches the :ATTEND relation, **has a non null result**. If for instance the user does not ATTEND any event, but has Artists and Hosts that s/he LIKES then I'd assume the query to still return results based on the second MATCH clause but that isn't happening.

What am I missing here?

-
Thanks,
A cypher nube

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UNION might be your best bet here, especially since the only thing you want are the :Event nodes, with no further processing.

```
MATCH (me:Person {emailId: 'abc@xyz.com'})-[:ATTEND]->(gig:Event)
RETURN gig
UNION
MATCH (me:Person {emailId: 'abc@xyz.com'})-[:LIKE]->(a:Artist)-[:PERFORMS]->(gig:Event)
RETURN gig
UNION
MATCH (me:Person {emailId: 'abc@xyz.com'})-[:LIKE]->(h:Host)-[:HOSTING]->(gig:Event)
RETURN gig
```

Answer (score 5):

If `MATCH` does not return anything then the query stops and that is why you have a problem. Solution is `OPTIONAL MATCH` so that it does not stop if the return is empty. You can try changing your query to this, so no matter if user attended the gig or not you will get results if he likes artists that performed on the gig.

```
optional match (me {emailId: 'abc@xyz.com'})-[attend:ATTEND]->(gig), 
(me)-[:LIKE]->(n)-[:PERFORMS|HOSTING]-(gig2) return gig,gig2
```

Answer (score 4):

Query from Tomaž Bratanič working. But there is a more compact alternative with a variable path length:

```
match (me:Person {emailId: 'abc@xyz.com'})
      -[:LIKE|ATTEND|PERFORMS|HOSTING*1..2]->
      (e:Event)
return e
```

Comment: I think this one may match on unintended :Events. For example, if you :LIKE someone who :ATTENDs an :Event, you'll get that event too.